# Линейный кусок кода с пробелами в начале и конце

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено

При попытке создать пример кода таким образом:

```
Текст комментария `     код      `
```

Увидим:
Текст комментария `код`

А в комментариях это будет так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Считаю такое поведение неприемлемым. Пробелы- это важно. Сайт посвящен программированию все-таки.

Answer (score 2):

```html
А если такой <code>   код  </code>?
```

А если такой    `код`  ?

Комментарии идут лесом, естественно.

Comment: Ну, это ж костыль. Путь разработчики движка пофиксят.

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, такое поведение обусловлено [спецификацией Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code):

> The backtick delimiters surrounding a code span may include spaces — one after the opening, one before the closing. This allows you to place literal backtick characters at the beginning or end of a code span:

```
A single backtick in a code span: `` ` ``

A backtick-delimited string in a code span: `` `foo` ``
```

> will produce:

```
<p>A single backtick in a code span: <code>`</code></p>

<p>A backtick-delimited string in a code span: <code>`foo`</code></p>
```

---

То же самое на Meta En.SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297113/2790048