# Комментарий, который вышел за рамки дозволенного

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн, комментарии, интерфейс

Блок кода, в комментариях под [этим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1187603/361068), перешёл все границы;) Возможно завёлся баг.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Удилил лишние пробелы - исправилось)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Всё равно странное поведение. Почему не переносит на следующую строку?

Comment: В комментария нет поддержки переноса строк. Возможно даже потому, что комментарии не предназначены для более чем одной строки кода)

Comment: `int sum = 0;  for (int i = 1; i < 117; i++)  {      sum += i;  }                                                                                                                        sum+=117;` Скопируем сюда, пожалуй.

Comment: @Qwertiy Kак так получилось? В коде у SE нет багов, есть тока неожиданные фичи (c) ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, не знаю, но там только ascii.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, `white-space: pre-wrap;` - зато переносы строк работают.

Comment: `.comment-copy{max-width: 100%; display: -webkit-inline-box;}`

Answer (score 6):

Как говорится, [за что боролись](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2471/265406)...

В настоящее время, если учесть, что повсеместно идёт борьба с пользователями старых браузеров, то необходимо использовать [новые](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_white-space_break-spaces) технологии по полной и заменить в стилях SO, для inline-вставки кода в комментарии, параметр свойства `white-space` с `pre-wrap`...:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

... на `break-spaces`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечно, это не панацея, но компромисс между поломанной вёрсткой и упованием на то, что "... тут же программисты".

Остаётся донести проблему и ждать. *А я, пожалуй, уже сейчас исправлю это у себя в расширении.*

Comment: Ну вообще-то 
`pre-wrap` - _Последовательности пробелов сохраняются так, как они указаны в источнике. Строки переносятся только там, где в источнике указаны символы новой строки и там, где в источнике указаны элементы <br>, и при необходимости для заполнения строчных боксов._
`pre-line` - _Последовательности пробелов объединяются в один пробел. Строки разбиваются по символам новой строки, по элементам <br>, и при необходимости для заполнения строчных боксов.._
Так что не надо менять `pre-wrap` на `break-spaces` - косяк где-то ещё.

Comment: @Qwertiy: а чуть ниже этого текста видели табличку? Нашли отличия? Просто значение довольно новое и не все разобрались ещё, зачем оно нужно и как работает. Ну, согласитесь, что на скриншотах явно `break-spaces` смотрится лучше.

Comment: Ну в принципе можно. Хотя пустая строка из пробелов тоже сильно полезной не выглядит.

Comment: @Qwertiy: согласен, потому и не панацея. С другой стороны, если она **имеет** значение, то её можно скопировать. Просто по рукам бить надо товарищей дающих "простыни" в комментах, а не в ответах.